# How to sort all elements in a dictionary based a defined rule of keys?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, ordereddictionary

I define a rule for keys of a dictionary. The rule is saved by a dict structure, *dict_RulesLabel*. Now I want to sort all elements of the dictionary based on my rule. But there is an error. How can I solve this problem?

```
Rules_2nd_order={('B', 'E'): {'E': 0.8695652173913043, 'L': 0.08695652173913043, 'B': 0.043478260869565216}, ('A', 'E'): {'E': 0.74, 'L': 0.18, 'STAB': 0.02, 'B': 0.06}, ('A', 'L'): {'E': 0.8, 'L': 0.08, 'B': 0.04}}
dict_RulesLabel={('A', 'A'): 0, ('A', 'L'): 1, ('A', 'B'): 2, ('A', 'Mod'): 3, ('A', 'C'): 4, ('A', 'E'): 5, ('A', 'D'): 6, ('B', 'E'): 7}
sortedRules_2nd_order = dict(sorted(Rules_2nd_order.items(), key=lambda x: dict_RulesLabel[x]))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/HONSignificanceTest/main.py", line 128, in <module>
    ExportRulestoDataframe(Rules_2nd_order, RulesLabelFileName)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/HONSignificanceTest/main.py", line 82, in ExportRulestoDataframe
    sortedRules_2nd_order = sorted(Rules_2nd_order.items(), key=lambda x: dict_RulesLabel[x])
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/HONSignificanceTest/main.py", line 82, in <lambda>
    sortedRules_2nd_order = sorted(Rules_2nd_order.items(), key=lambda x: dict_RulesLabel[x])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: Replace `key=lambda x: dict_RulesLabel[x]` with `key=lambda x: dict_RulesLabel[x[0]]` in the third line

Comment: Because `x` is taken from `Rules_2nd_order.items()`, so it's a pair `(k,v)` from the dictionary, and you want dict_RulesLabel[k], not dict_RulesLabel[(k,v)]